# How can i filter first all the images types when using OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void Add_Files_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
    openFileDialog.Filter = "All Images Files (*.png;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.tiff;*.tif)|*.png;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.tiff;*.tif";
    openFileDialog.Filter = "PNG Portable Network Graphics (*.png)|" + "*.png";
    openFileDialog.Filter = "JPEG File Interchange Format (*.jpg *.jpeg *jfif)|" + "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jfif";
    openFileDialog.Filter = "BMP Windows Bitmap (*.bmp)|" + "*.bmp";
    openFileDialog.Filter = "TIF Tagged Imaged File Format (*.tif *.tiff)|" + "*.tif;*.tiff";
    openFileDialog.Filter = "GIF Graphics Interchange Format (*.gif)|" + "*.gif";
  }
```

In this way when i click the button the default and only option is the GIF file type. I can't then change it to any other file type.

I want that the default first option will be All Images File and then that i will be able to change for each image format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join all strings with `|` character and assign it

```
dialog.Filter = "All Images Files (*.png;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.tiff;*.tif)|*.png;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.tiff;*.tif" +
            "|PNG Portable Network Graphics (*.png)|*.png" +
            "|JPEG File Interchange Format (*.jpg *.jpeg *jfif)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jfif" +
            "|BMP Windows Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp" +
            "|TIF Tagged Imaged File Format (*.tif *.tiff)|*.tif;*.tiff" +
            "|GIF Graphics Interchange Format (*.gif)|*.gif";
```